# sqlconnection missing type or namespace reference

Tags: c#

I have a sql query that I want to use to get results from a database. When I try to open a sqlconnection, my code won't compile and I get an error asking if i am missing a using directive.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;


namespace HackOffice.Superadmin
{
    public partial class FoundUsBreakdown : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grabData();
        }
        private void grabData()
        {
            string chartDataQuery = "select AccountType, COUNT(*) Entries from HackOffice.dbo.OnlineSignups group by AccountType";
            using (sqlconnection connection = new sqlconnection(connectionString));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm confused because I have all the same using directives on other pages and I am not getting the same error on those pages.

Comment: It's `SqlConnection`, not `sqlconnection` (case sensitive).

Comment: wow. you can tell im new. thanks! If you put as answer i will mark it.

Comment: Use Visual studio. It really helps in these kinds of issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class names are case sensitive in C#. You need `SqlConnection`, not `sqlconnection`.

Also, you're creating an empty `using` statement which will dispose the resource immediately. When you open a using block, you'll want to put all the code that uses the `IDisposable` resource inside the block:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   // Code that uses SqlConnection goes inside the block.
}
```

Comment: solid answer. will accept when i can. also i did not realize that. Thank you!